PHP Mock a class that implements an interface
I am trying to test a factory that it returns the correct instance. But ApiAuthRequest class has to implement a specific interface in order for the test to succeed. How I can do it?
I have tried to create a class in the test, which works but I am not sure if it's the right way.
public function factory_returns_correct_instance(AllowedHttpMethod $httpMethod): void
{
    $request = $this->partialMock(ApiAuthRequest::class, function(MockInterface $request) {
        $request->shouldReceive('getModel')->andReturn($this->model);
    });

    $restrictor = ModelRestrictionFactory::create($request, $httpMethod);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(ModelSystem::class, $restrictor);
}

// If I do this in the test class, test works.
class ApiAuthRequest  implements HasModelSystemRestriction
{

}


We need more insight. May I know what ApiAuthRequest is for? What about ModelRestrictionFactory? What does HasModelSystemRestriction implement? What error are you getting if you don't implement that interface? If factory_returns_correct_instance is a test case, why do you have AllowedHttpMethod $httpMethod as an argument but I see no data provider or similar?

The purpose of mocking is to fake something. You don't need to understand how it works. My goal is to mock ApiAuthRequest  that implements HasModelSystemRestriction interface. In that case, test will succeed

You are right, but wanted to know more because sometimes people misuse the framework, overcomplicating everything. I just wanted to know if that was the case or not. But also know what error you were getting, not only because it never happened to me but for anyone having a similar issue can understand and know more about it based on the error itself. I never had this issue before and I have been testing for 5 years and I tested a lot of things, that is why I am asking, never faced this issue at all in Laravel

Is ModelSystem different from HasModelSystemRestriction?

This is possible by using \Mockery::mock(); where the first argument is the class followed by the interface.
public function factory_returns_model_system_instance(AllowedHttpMethod $httpMethod): void
    {
        $request = \Mockery::mock(ApiAuthRequest::class, HasModelSystemRestriction::class);
        $request->shouldReceive('getModel')->andReturn($this->model);
        $request->shouldReceive('instanceof')->with(HasModelSystemRestriction::class)->andReturn(true);

        $restrictor = ModelRestrictionFactory::create($request, $httpMethod);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(ModelSystem::class, restrictor);
    }

